# How To Remove "Ctrl + Backspace" Special Character?

Tags: c++, filter, character

I have a server written in C++, and when receiving a chat string, I'd like to remove weird special characters like the one created by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Backspace</kbd> (though not other symbols like :)]>_ etc.)

I'm using Boost, too.

edit: Why'd this get -1'd? It's a legit question.

Comment: Please specify what kind of weird character that would be. On my GUI, Ctrl + Backspace simply erases the previous word...

Comment: I could not understand why this was a bad question, unless the submitter should have known what the character did. However, there are a lot of applications where streams of characters come in from all kinds of places that have cruft in them and they need to be filtered out.

Comment: Turns out it was ASCII character 8 (binary: 00001000).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like `isprint` might help. It returns true for any printable character, ie. not for control characters and whitespaces. For a list of what is considered printable and what not, take a look at [this table](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cctype/).

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used it, and this probably isn't the best way to do it, but have you considered trying the boost regex library (i.e., regex_replace)?